# Is it bad practice to store a struct member value in local var with a shorter name?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I used a struct to store some data that I read from a file. The struct members are a float and an array of unsigned integers. After the file is read none of the values will ever change. The value I want to store locally is is one of the unsigned integers contained in the struct member array.

Is it bad practice to de reference the struct pointer to the value and store it in a local variable to be used later or should I just be writing out foo->vals[MY_NUMBER] every time that I want to use that value for something.

Thank you for taking the time to check out my question.

Currently my code is set up exactly as I've written below with out using things like:

```
 while (timer < config->values[MY_NUMBER]){ /* code*/}
```

my_struct.c :

```
typedef struct Config {
  float MY_FLOAT;
  unsigned int values[TOTAL_PARAMS];
} Config;
```

main.c:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  Config *config = load_config();

  int timer = 0;
  int finish_time = config->values[FIN_TIME];

  int rand_min_max[2] = {config->values[MIN],config->values[MAX]};

   /*... code*/

  while (timer < finish_time) {
    randomizer_func(rand_min_max);
    /* Code*/
  }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is `Config* config` a pointer? In idiomatic C I would expect to see static allocation on the stack and pass a pointer into `load_config` to populate it. e.g. `Config config; load_config( &config );`

Comment: my load config function creates a new config pointer with malloc then opens reads and closes the file then returns a pointer the the config struct. config is freed at the end of main. Is this something I shouldn't be doing?

Comment: @Shwig That's a perfectly reasonable approach.

Comment: It’s not necessarily bad in itself, but in C it helps to avoid `malloc` when you can.

Comment: @Dai Care to elaborate? `malloc` is not evil. Programmers who forget `free`, on the other hand, are another matter. You can't assume that every data structure used in a given app is going to fit on the stack, or that it only needs to be used in the function that allocates it. (`malloc` in a tight, frequently-executed loop *is* evil, but that's a separate discussion.)

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with making your code more readable and saving typing. Even without the compiler optimizations that are likely to resolve the additional variables to the same symbol, the cost of adding a few variables is negligible. As with everything there is a balance to be struck. You wouldn't want to go wild renaming everything and having the number of variables grow like weeds in a vacant lot, but for a few, it's A-OK.

Comment: @3Dave As you said, because of the risk of forgetting `free`, and it's easier to reason about the lifetime of stack-allocated objects than heap-allocated objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optimizer should clean this up, so I doubt there'd be a perf impact. The question is: does it make your code more readable and/or easier to maintain? Using temp variables in this way is pretty common. Unless you can come up with a *reason* that it's "bad," go for it.

Another thing to consider is that, by copying to a local variable and avoiding dereferencing the pointer every time, you're potentially speeding up access to the value in question. HOWEVER: that value is likely cached after the first access, and, again the Magical, Wonderful Optimizer will probably fix that. (But, as an engineer, you should never count on that - test and validate rather than assume.)

In my opinion (cringe), you're fine. Go with it.

Answer (score 3):

No, this doesn't seem like a bad practice, without further context.

Since the config values will not change and you're just making a copy of the individual config parameters you need, you're making the code a little bit more readable without introducing any downsides.